# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'access_token'

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL + Angular 8 + HashLocationStrategy and running into the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'access_token'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'access_token'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2464)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2445)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
```

We updated our msal library to 1.3.0 version as described here - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1447 but the issue still is not resolved. We did not make any code changes except library upgradation.

Can anyone help us fix this issue?